# Connect Bluetooth device from two apps

Tags: java, android

I can't create connection to Bluetooth device from my app because another app is already connected. Is there a chance to create a connection and receive data by two different connections?

Comment: has your question been answered? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes!**

You can make a connection to several devices (from your device). The server/client (app) knows with which server/client (app) to connect to through the specified UUID (a unique identifier) which both share.

Read the sections "Connecting as a server" and "Connecting as a client" from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

> The string is an identifiable name of your service, which the system
>   will automatically write to a new Service Discovery Protocol (SDP)
>   database entry on the device (the name is arbitrary and can simply be
>   your application name). The UUID is also included in the SDP entry and
>   will be the basis for the connection agreement with the client device.
>   That is, when the client attempts to connect with this device, it will
>   carry a UUID that uniquely identifies the service with which it wants
>   to connect. These UUIDs must match in order for the connection to be
>   accepted [...].

Comment: Its the same device, but different apps on my device. Probably they use same UUID. So when one app is connected and receive data, second one can't connect and receive that data.

Comment: so, you have to use a different UUID in your app. generate your own one: https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

Comment: @Will were u able to make the 2 apps receive data from the device??